# How can i delete Ubuntu from the computer?

Tags: uninstall, delete

I want to clear my computer from everything but i have no clue how I will do this with Ubuntu Plz help me before i will throw my computer throgh the window. With other words i don't want to have anything from Ubuntu left in my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to hear about that! There's no need of killing any computer! Simply install another operating system (OS). Any OS you like. During the install process it will probably ask you where you want it installed. Choose erase ENTIRE disk and install. After erasing entire disk, it will probably ask you for a new partition. Create a new partition any way you see fit and install OS to it. That's all!

Comment: Even that i have my Windows disk in, it's chose to start normal with Ubuntu. Why is that so?

Comment: @FalleH you have to select to boot from the windows disk. You have to press a button _(depending on your computer)_ that gets out a "boot menu" when the computer just powres on. It might be F11 or Delete. Try looking on the first screen that appears when you just power on your computer

Comment: @MinaMichael When i have klicked del and after that i can chose between Main Advanced Power Boot Tools Exit... I guess i will klick on boot?

Comment: @FalleH I don't think so. I think "boot" will just take you to Ubuntu. You need to boot from your CD so you should search for it. you can try though

Comment: @FalleH urw. sorry to see you're removing ubuntu XD

Answer (score 0):

I Have solved the problem, BIG tnx to the people that helped me. The only thing i had to do wast to make so that the cd was in first boot place or something like that. Tnx again.